# Word for country in which parents were born

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that refers to the country in which one's parents were born. Something similar to mother-tongue except for location instead of language?

Comment: Similar to *mother-tongue?* But that's the language *you* were brought up with as a child. Which is not necessarily the mother-tongue of your *mother*. Each of your parents has a mother-tongue and [birthland](http://uk.ask.com/question/what-is-the-definition-of-birthland) (either or both of which they may have in common). You also have your mother-tongue and birthland, which may be the same or different to either or both of your parents.

Comment: Good question. Inappropriate example. Please remove the example and if possible use another.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now that's an interesting complication there. If the parents speak different languages and the child is brought up in an environment of a third language, how would one define 'mother tongue'? Many children today have their 'nationality' more by choice than prescription. So it would be with language?

Comment: @Kris  The children grow up being  *bilingual* or *trilingual*. I have cousins who switch from Italian, French (parents) and English (native land) with ease. I would say that *mother tongue* describes the use of a single language.

Comment: I would say: "My parents' homeland"

Comment: Besides "fatherland", which might have unwanted Nazi overtones, I would suggest "ancestral homeland".

Comment: Since your motherland or fatherland is where you were born, presumably your parent’s would be your _grandmotherland_ or _grandfatherland_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe that is a misunderstanding of the word.  The mother and father imply that the country in question is your mother/father.

Comment: My problem with your question is this: where a person was born may (or may not) be the place of origin of one's culture, language, or ethnicity. For example, the recently-deceased King of Thailand was born to Thai parents in Cambridge, Massachusetts. To refer to Massachusetts as the Thai parents' homeland, motherland, or fatherland would be ludicrous.

Comment: @KumaAra, Merriam Webster's defines motherland and fatherland as the location of one's birth. What is your source for your metaphorical usage?

Comment: I said "I believe" because I am unsure.  But my understanding of motherland comes from various sources that discuss why motherland is used to give the feeling of love, caring, and nurturing towards one's home country.  These are traits associated with mothers.  Hence we are using the term mother to describe the country to show our affection for the country and the perceived nurturing care we get back.  One place I was reading about this was: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/identity-crisis-motherland-fatherland/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps **[motherland](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/motherland)**

> one's native land or, sometimes, the land of one's ancestors;
>   a country thought of as originator or source

Similarly **[fatherland](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/fatherland)**

> a person's native land or country; the land or country of one's ancestors

Comment: I think either this isn't the right answer, or OP doesn't quite understand what he's asking. One's *mother/father/birthland* ***might*** be "the country in which one's parents were born". But then again it might not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that both terms are somewhat vague. I can't think of a term that is explicitly limited to the land of your parents birth, other than *parents' place of birth*. Both motherland and fatherland convey an attitude as much as a location.

Comment: -1 'Ancestors' does not necessarily include immediate parents and often does **not**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you, to a non-native speaker the words; *motherland* and *fatherland* deceptively look like words that refer directly to your parents' birthplaces.

Comment: "Fatherland" might have unwanted connotations of Nazi Germany. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatherland

Comment: @nohat That is a good point. A number of otherwise innocuous words become uncomfortable because of use by or association with horrific events. In the US, no one thinks of the flower when they hear *columbine*.

Comment: @bib That’s not true. The flower is the first thing to come to mind.

Comment: @tchrist Huh, doves are the first thing that come to my mind… (Then again, botany and I were never bosom buddies, and I haven't the faintest idea what a columbine flower looks like.)

Comment: As a native English speaker, if someone says motherland or fatherland, I would only assume they mean their own native country, the country in which they were born in.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking at some figures from Google Books here...

> **1 - predominantly OUR**
>   *our/my **motherland*** [79,600](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) / [22,200](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20motherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *our/my **fatherland*** [105,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks) / [53,800](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *our/my **homeland*** [160,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our%20homeland%22&tbm=bks) / [88,500](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20homeland%22&tbm=bks)
>
> **2 - predominantly MY**
>   *our/my **birthland*** [105](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our%20birthland%22&tbm=bks) / [431](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20birthland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *our/my **native land*** [130,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our%20native%20land%22&tbm=bks) / [234,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20native%20land%22&tbm=bks)
>   ***land of*** our/my **birth** [130,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22land%20of%20our%20birth%22&tbm=bks) / [256,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22land%20of%20my%20birth%22&tbm=bks)

---

The above results suggest to me that *mother/father/homeland* are primarily associated with identifying ***shared*** biological and cultural origins. When an individual simply wants to identify his ***personal*** background, he's likely to avoid terms which are primarily nationalistic/militaristic...

> *defend the/our/my motherland* [8,470](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22defend%20the%20motherland%22&tbm=bks) / [8,060](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22defend%20our%20motherland%22&tbm=bks) / [186](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22defend%20my%20motherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *fight for the/our/my fatherland* [48,500](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22fight%20for%20the%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks) / [1,320](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22fight%20for%20our%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks) / [237](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22fight%20for%20my%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *the/our/my homeland security* [1,780,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20homeland%20security%22&tbm=bks) / [122,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our%20homeland%20security%22&tbm=bks) / [600](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20homeland%20security%22&tbm=bks)

---

Quite apart from those connotations (which are presumably unwanted in OP's context), there's a literal/figurative clash in forms such as *my father's motherland, my parent's fatherland,* etc. Plus there's obviously no reason to mention your parents' origins at all *unless they're different to yours*. But if you have to, the general preference is quite clear...

> *my parents' motherland* [5](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20parents%20motherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *my parents' fatherland* [4](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20parents%20fatherland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *my parents' **homeland*** [**1,150**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20parents%20homeland%22&tbm=bks) <--- **(as per Mari-Lou's earlier comment)**
>   *my parents' birthland* [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20parents%20birthland%22&tbm=bks)
>   *my parents' native land* [158](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22my%20parents%20native%20land%22&tbm=bks)
>   *land of my parents' birth* [78](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20motherland%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22land%20of%20my%20parents%20birth%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Sorry! Attribution noted!

Comment: Technically, of course, _my parents’ birthland(s)_ and _land(s) of my parents’ birth(s)_ are the only two options that fit exactly. One's homeland, motherland, fatherland, or native land is not necessarily the same country one was born in.

Comment: @Janus: I'd certainly use *birthland* if it was important to be precise about "natal location", but given OP likens his target word to *mother tongue* I lean towards *homeland* as more evocative of "the land you grew up in" (as per "the language you grew up using most naturally and fluently").

Answer (score -1):

"Ancestral home" or "ancestral homeland" is appropriate. That phrase will work regardless of where the speaker was born.

Comment: As @Kris previously stated: 'Ancestors' does not necessarily include immediate parents and often does not.

If you told me your ancestral homeland was Ireland, I would assume it had been at least 3 or 4 generations since someone immigrated from Ireland.

Comment: Parents are certainly ancestors. In genealogy terms, parents are direct ancestors. "Immediate parents" is a phrase I have never heard.

Comment: Yes, of course they are.  But if your goal is to express the idea of where your parents specifically were born, then ancestral home will not give that impression.  One's parent's home is not necessarily one's ancestral home.  You could be from a long line of Irishmen, then your grandparents moved to England and gave birth to your mother.  So your ancestral home is Ireland, but your mother's country of birth is England.  ---  Note that the OP asked specifically for a word to describe the country where your parents were born.

Comment: In this day and age, it is more common (especially in America) for one's ancestral home and one's parent's country of birth to be different.  As humans have moved so many times over the centuries.  Hence the need for the term ancestral home in the first place.  To track where one's family originally came from (but no longer lives in).

Comment: To clarify @KumaAra's point, while it is true that, as a conceptual matter, one's ancestors include one's parents, *ancestral home* and similar phrases, normally stands for **the** place where **most** of one's **known** (even if only vaguely known) ancestors lived (so that the history of one's family has been significantly shaped by the culture of that place).